# Why doesn't fractions.Fraction have __int__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, fractions

When using `int(fractions.Fraction)`, it returns the corresponding value of the fraction.

Example

```
from fractions import Fraction

int(Fraction(12, 3)) # Outputs 4
```

However, fraction.Fraction doesn't have an `__int__` method. So how is this happening?